# C# Generics type when using this keyword

Tags: c#, generics, this

The objects I am putting together are to allow an object to expose itself as something that can be transformed by another object of the same type. Think along the lines of merge, but the operations are not generic/straightforward such that you could use reflection to simply get all the properties and perform some predetermined set of operations. I have therefore decided to try and implement it as objects that expose themselves as *Transformable* and attach to them an object that knows how to perform the transformation (which can be interchanged). The compilable code I have so far is:

```
public interface ITransformer<TType> where TType : class
{
    void Transform(TType source, TType destination);
}

public interface ITransformable<TType> where TType : class
{
    bool Locked { get; set; }
    ITransformer<TType> Transformer { get; set; }

    void TransformFrom(TType source);
}

public class MyTransformer : ITransformer<MyTransformable>
{
    public void Transform(MyTransformable source, MyTransformable destination)
    {
        // Perform some logic for the transform
    }
}

public class MyTransformable : ITransformable<MyTransformable>
{
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public ITransformer<MyTransformable> Transformer { get; set; }

    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public uint Value2 { get; set; }
    public bool Value3 { get; set; }

    public void TransformFrom(MyTransformable source)
    {
        Transformer.Transform(source, this);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the type *MyTransformable* contains some data (Value1 - Value3) as well as a *Locked* state and the *Transformer* object will know how to perform the transform for this item (generics ensuring only transformers capable of acting on the *MyTransformer* type are allowed).

My problem is that I don't want all new objects of type *Transformable* to have to repeat the call to

```
public void TransformFrom(MyTransformable source)
{
    Transformer.Transform(source, this);
}
```

So was hoping I could change *MyTransformable* to

```
public abstract class Transformable<TType> : ITransformable<TType> where TType : class
{
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public ITransformer<TType> Transformer { get; set; }

    public void TransformFrom(TType source)
    {
        Transformer.Transform(source, this);  // ERROR! this is type Transformable<TType> not TType
    }
}

public class MyTransformable : Transformable<MyTransformable>
{

}
```

But of course this won't compile due to the error I highlight. I feel like I have missed the point somewhere along the line. Could anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: How would you expect this to work: `Transformable<int>` ? There is no way `this` can be of type `int`.

Comment: If you're doing a lossless conversion, you may want to look into implementing casting operators for your classes instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=vs.100).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You'll need to enforce some generic constraints on `ITransformer<TType>` and `ITransformable<TType>` in order to achieve what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is add a hook for the derived type to expose the final, real `TType` implementation (or simply `this`).  This is best done through an abstract property.

```
public abstract class Transformable<TType> : ITransformable<TType>
{
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public ITransformer<TType> Transformer { get; set; }

    protected abstract TType Value { get; }

    public void TransformFrom(TType source)
    {
        Transformer.Transform(source, Value); 
    }
}

public class MyOtherTransformable : Transformable<MyTransformable>
{
    protected override MyTransformable Value
    {
        get { return this; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works a treat. Would have loved to not require the final sub classes to have to override anything, but the penalty from using a `dynamic` cast seems worse. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 4, you can use a cast to `dynamic`:

```
public void TransformFrom(TType source)
{
    Transformer.Transform(source, (dynamic)this);
}
```

This allows the CLR to do the parameter type-matching at runtime based on the real type (closed generic) of the object at the time of execution, preventing the compile-time error. At runtime, the CLR can easily tell that `source` and `this` are the same type and will perform the call.

The upside is it solves your problem. The downside is that use of `dynamic` is an inherently reflective process, which is first slower and second can hide bugs that will cause runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It'll result in more casting than you are probably comfortable with and may even defeat the purpose of what you're trying to do, but this compiles:

```
public interface ITransformable { }

public interface ITransformer<TType>
    where TType: ITransformable
{
    void Transform(ITransformable source, ITransformable destination);
}

public interface ITransformable<TType> : ITransformable
    where TType: ITransformable
{
    bool Locked { get; set; }
    ITransformer<TType> Transformer { get; set; }

    void TransformFrom(TType source);
}

public class MyTransformer : ITransformer<MyTransformable>
{
    public void Transform(ITransformable source, ITransformable destination)
    {
        if (source.GetType() != destination.GetType())
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        // Perform some logic for the transform
    }
}

public abstract class Transformable<TType> : ITransformable<TType> where TType: ITransformable
{
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public ITransformer<TType> Transformer { get; set; }

    public void TransformFrom(TType source)
    {
        Transformer.Transform(source, this);
    }
}

public class MyTransformable : Transformable<MyTransformable>
{

}
```

Comment: Inside the Transform method of the Transformer, you'll need to check that the two ITransformable parameters are the same actual type.